# get wrong result function jquery javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following script. But I am receiving a wrong result for `x_b_bbetrag`.

When do an calculation exp 100/108 I get 9.92 instead of 92.59.
What am I missing here?

Code below:

```
var betrag = 100
var kurs = 1
var minkl= 1
var msatz= 0.08    
$("#x_b_betrag").change(function() {
var betrag = $("#x_b_betrag").val();
var kurs = $("#x_b_kurs").val();
var minkl =$("input[name='x_b_mwstinkl']:checked").val();
var  msatz =$("input[name='x_b_mwst']:checked").val();
if (minkl == "1"){
$("#x_b_rechenbetrag").val((betrag * kurs).toFixed(2)); 
$("#x_b_bbetrag").val( ( (betrag * kurs) /(1 + msatz) ).toFixed(2));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `parseFloat`
multiplication, division and subtraction automatically parse string to number. for summation you need to parse it.

```
$("#x_b_bbetrag").val( ( (betrag * kurs) /(1 + parseFloat(msatz) ) ).toFixed(2));
```

///1 + "1" = 11 not 2

Answer (score 1):

Parse your inputs into numbers.

For example :

```
var betrag = parseFloat($("#x_b_betrag").val());
```

[MDN on parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)

Answer (score 1):

The value of the `msatz` variable is not `0.08` but `"0.08"`. It's a string, so when you add one to it, the number will be converted to a string so that they can be concatenated, and the result is `"10.08"` not `1.08`. The string will implicitly be converted to a number when you use it in the division, as it's not possible to divide by a string.

Parse the string into a number:

```
var msatz = parseFloat($("input[name='x_b_mwst']:checked").val());
```